# "Safe" rebasing after branch has been pushed already

Tags: git

I have the following situation, which happens quite often to me/us:

I branched `some_feature` from `master`. Lets call me the main developer of that feature. At some point I pushed the branch to my remote `origin`, a remote colleague did some small changes, pushed them and I pulled them. In the mean time, `master` has changed. Because I want to have a clean history, I would prefer to rebase instead of merging, which is now a problem, because the branch has already been pushed.

The best idea I had, is to create a new local branch based on `some_feature` and to rebase that one. That way, `some_feature` should not be modified, the commits should be replayed onto the latest `master` and in case I ever push that branch, it should be safe.

Can you confirm that this workflow will not harm any coworkers or propose a better workflow for this situation?

Comment: That's fine, as long as everyone else working on the project knows to switch from `some_feature` to your new branch should you push that. Is it really so bad to merge `master` into `some_feature`?

Comment: @chepner Once you tell everybody there is no need to make a new branch. Actually, keeping it around will probably lead to more confusion if somebody did not get the message.